# Using an array in an Object

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm using user input to determine the size of my array. 
This array will be used by another object.
Additionally, this will be looping so the user will potentially change the array size.
What's the best way to do this?
And since the array is used by an object, would it be better to pass the array in the constructor or pass the size and create the array in the class?
I was thinking some sort of a new delete array combination?
Am I off the mark here?

Answer (score 1):

For generic, dynamic array-like needs, the best option is probably the `std::vector` class. Just create it where it is needed, I'd say into the class.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector is a resizable array provided by the standard template library. To get it,

```
#include <vector>
```

There is plenty of material on the internet for how to use vectors, e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/ . Without further information, a good first start would be to use std::vector's inside of your container.